# Make an Image Pass-through so it does not block interactions

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make an image visible but have interactions pass-through.

For this example: We will use links as interactions on the page. I have a series of links on a page but in front of it I have an image. I want to be able to pass-through that image without interacting with it and click on the links behind it. Whether or not the links are visible that should not matter, i just want to be able to pass through the image in the front.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `pointer-events: none;` - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for CSS 4's `pointer-events` CSS property. Set this property of `img` as none. eg:-

```
img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```